# How do I move a pointer in C++?

Tags: c++

This is a stupid question but I just have no idea how to accomplish this.

I have an object and a vector. At a set time during execution, I need to put this object in the vector and overwrite this object with a new one. I currently have this,

```
std::vector<Cube*> cubes;
Cube* workingCube = new Cube();
...
cubes.insert(cubes.begin(), workingCube);
workingCube = new Cube();
```

which I assume is wrong because of some pointer-related reason. I can't figure out how to do this properly though.

Comment: You could use placement new, but this is bad design. Maybe smart pointers can solve the underlying problem.

Comment: @CarlNorum bit of a typo on my part, fixed it

Comment: @BatchyX: I fail to see how placement new is related to the question.

Answer (score 10):

It's a lot cleaner and far less leak-prone if we avoid pointers and explicit dynamic allocation:

```
std::vector<Cube> cubes;

Cube workingCube;
cubes.insert(cubes.begin(), workingCube);
workingCube = Cube();
```

If `Cube` is expensive to copy but cheap to move, you can `std::move(workingCube)` into the container instead.  If `Cube` is expensive to both move and copy, use a `std::unique_ptr<Cube>` and move it into the container.

Whatever you do, **do not use raw pointers to own things**.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with that, as long as you always remember which pointer "owns" the object, i.e., who is responsible to `delete` the object when it is no longer needed.  In your case, you transfer the owning pointer to the vector and at some point, you should delete all pointers in the vector.